# Validate script references in vue html/template

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, quasar-framework, vetur

What I'm using

- VSCode
- Quasar (Vue)
- Typescript
- Eslint/@typescript-eslint
- Prettier / prettierhtml / Vetur

Current issue:

Until recently, injected script in the `<template>` of vue files (e.g. `onSignIn` in `<div @click="onSignIn">` was checked against available variables/methods in the `<script lang="ts">` part. This has now stopped working and I couldn't figure out what's the reason. Playing around with VSCode/Vetur/eslint settings wasn't successful either so far.

As the above hasn't worked earlier either but just since I started my latest project, I'm not sure what settings is responsible for that part anyway (Veturs' `HTML > Validate > Scripts` apparently is not enough) and my first question is, whether it works for you; the second, if you know exactly why/why not (?).

Answer (score 1):

Setting `vetur.experimental.templateInterpolationService: true` did the trick.